# wordpress image_default_link_type no way works

Tags: wordpress

what is the way to change the default link url when inserting an image, so its always 'none' rather then displaying the link in wordpress?

I try all way that I found: http://wpsites.net/wordpress-tips/5-ways-to-change-default-image-links/

I have Version 4.2.2.

But nothing works.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I always this function to update this settings. just placed in your `functions.php` and it will do the trick.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'default_attachment_display_settings' );
function default_attachment_display_settings() {
    update_option( 'image_default_align', 'none' );
    update_option( 'image_default_link_type', 'none' );
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesnt works.

I try to paste it both in my child theme's functions.php than in my parent theme's functions.php.

Thanks

Comment: @ValeBoccaccio that is really odd, do you get any errors in debug mode? what theme are you using?

Comment: no any errors, Im using Fundify (http://ignitiondeck.com/id/themes/fundify/) with Ignitiondeck crowdfunding plugins